Referentiality of "what" in free relatives
The sentence (1a) is ambiguous, as it seems to allow both the interpretation in (1b), where what you ate and what I ordered refer to the same referent, and the interpretation in (1c), where the second what refers to the same kind. Here, I assume this reading of (1c) is just coerced by the situation, that is, a pragmatic interpretation, and that the basic meaning of what in what I ordered is a specific entity, not a kind.
(1)
a. What you ate is what I ordered.
b. The food that you ate is the food that I ordered. (the same referent, e.g., You ate my pasta.)
c. The food that you ate is the same kind of food that I ordered. (the same kind, e.g., I also ate pasta.)
Therefore, what I ordered in (2a) is mostly interpreted as that particular food that I ordered even though both readings may be possible. On the other hand, what you ate in (2b) is interpreted as the kind or type of the food you ate because the fact that it is impossible to order the particular food that someone ate coerces the kind reading.
(2)
a. You ate what I ordered. (referential reading)
b. I ordered what you ate. (coerced kind reading)
If we want to convey the kind reading, we use the same one instead of what as in (3).
(3)
a. You ate the same one I ordered.
b. I ordered the same one you ate.
What do you think? Do you agree with my assumption that what used in free relatives basically refers to a specific thing, not a kind?

I would understand 2b as referring to entity more readily than kind: “That dinner you just ate, I was the one who ordered it [for you]”. What makes you say that, “it is impossible to order the particular food that someone ate”? It’s perfectly possible. It’s obviously not possible to order the specific food that someone else has already eaten, but the two past-tense forms don’t imply that the eating took place before the ordering here.

I don't think the answer lies in the status of "what" as a "free relative."  I find the same ambiguity if I replace "what" with "the pasta."  "You ate the pasta I (had) ordered" and "I (had) ordered the pasta you ate" both have "same entity" and "kind" readings.
